# Lex Parser & CodeIgniter, conditionnal weird behavior

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, pyrocms-lex

I'm using lexpyrocms parser as a package installed with composer along with a codeigniter framework with HMVC, which allows me to use  {{pseudo-variable}} in my templates/views.

I have a very weird behavior with the parser syntax in my view:

I have this simple $modules array as data  that I can print_r() in the view/template

```
$modules = 
Array ( 
       [users] => stdClass Object ( [id_mdl] => 8 [name_mdl] => users ),
       [actions] => stdClass Object ( [id_mdl] => 9 [name_mdl] => actions ) 
);
```

If I use basic Lex syntax, I can display the name_mdl without problem with

`{{modules}} {{name_mdl}} {{/modules}}` => output 'users' and 'actions'

but when I use the conditional 'if' inside the loop, I get a wrong matching when I test if a variable exists :

```
{{modules}}

    {{name_mdl}} 

{{/modules}}
```

this outputs correctly `users actions`

```
{{modules}}

    {{if exists name_mdl}} 
    name_mdl OK {{name_mdl}} 
    {{endif}}

{{/modules}}
```

but this does not output anything:

```
{{modules}}

    {{if not exists name_mdl}} 
    name_mdl  NOT OK {{name_mdl}} 
    {{endif}}

{{/modules}}
```

This   outputs `'name_mdl NOT OK users name_mdl NOT OK actions'`
the parser displays correctly a variable it just recused as existing in the condition..

I've searched a bit everywhere but it looks like an orphan problem, can't find a clue anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I managed to get rid of this strange behavior, but I'm not sure which part of the changement I've made solved the problem ...So for what it's worth :

The error I faced was that in a loop `{{list_of_things}}{{/list_of_things}}` the checking of an existing variable with conditional `if exists` wasn't possible, though the display of this variable worked fine :

```
{{list_of_things}}

    {{ list_name }} <-- display the list_name of each entry  

    {{ if exists list_name }} 
        The condition was never met, tough the data 'list_name' can be displayed above
    {{ endif }} 

{{/list_of_things}}
```

---

I did two things after that, and got rid-off the problem...

1- I moved the declaration of the Lex Parser `$this->parser = new Lex\Parser();`

from my front controller `application/modules/my_module/module_controller.php`

into the constructor of my extending core controller class `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

2- I cleaned up my views folder cause there where some double file from earlier development :

to be noted : the view called was and is *application/modules/my_module/views/theme/my_template.php*

- before :

  `modules/my_module/views/
                       my_template.php`

  `modules/my_module/views/theme/
                       my_template.php`
- after :

  `modules/my_module/views/`

  `modules/my_module/views/theme/
                       my_template.php`

---

So my best guess is that HMVC messed a bit the Lex Parser with the 'loaded_paths', and that two views with the same name in the same module (even though not in the same directory) can lead to unexpected behavior .. but I don't see why the hell that would change the conditionals of the parser ...